# Referencing variable form ID in django

Tags: django

I am having trouble figuring out how to reference the (variable) name of a form in django. This is the code I currently have:

in `email_edit.html`:

```
{% for email in email_list %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form action="/emails/edit/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="{{ email.id }}" value=" {{email}}"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="action"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
{% endfor %}

<p>Add new</p>
    <form action="/emails/edit/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text"  value="" name="add_email">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="action">
```

```
def email_edit(request):
    email_list = Email.objects.order_by('email')
    if request.POST:
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        if action == "Add":
            Email.objects.create(email=request.POST['add_email'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/emails/edit/')
        if action == 'Delete':
            Email.objects.filter(id={{ emails.id }}).delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/emails/edit/')
        if action == "Update":
            Email.objects.filter(id= {{ emails.id }}).update(name=request.POST[{{ emails.id }}])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/emails/edit/'))
```

What goes in `{{ email.id }}` in the `views.py` file to correctly reference the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to be rude, I think you might want to take a step back at what you're trying to accomplish. You have a list of emails that you want to then edit or delete. You don't really need to submit a form to get to another view in which you are going to edit or delete one of these records.

You'll most definitely need a form on an edit or delete view to post your values, but in the case of this list, I'm 99.9% sure you just need an anchor tag to edit or delete:

```
{% for email in email_list %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{email}}></td>
        <td><a href="{% url edit_email email.id %}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url delete_email email.id %}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that makes sense.

[Followup Answer]
Given the code you set up, I would make each row would be it's own form, and the email field would need to have a non-dynamic name. Otherwise, it's going to be tougher to access that value in the request.POST collection. Here's how I would set that up:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    email_list = MyModel.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        if action == 'Edit':
            #do edit
        else:
            #do delete
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'email_list' : email_list})

#template.html
{% for email in email_list %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <form action="." method="post">
        <td>{{ email }}<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ email }}" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" /></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1 nice answer. The edit portion of his code isn't shown, but its possible that it updates the email value. Your suggestion is still valid for the delete even if that is the case.

Comment: Hi Brandon, Thanks for the response. I agree with you completely with what you're saying. I'm just starting Django and trying to play around with it to figure out some of the basics. No doubt I'm doing things in odd and non-practical ways. Having said that, I'm still interested in completing this page. How would I reference the variable form name? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks DTing. I would definitely make that delete a two-step process. David, as DTing pointed out, if there's some additional action you're doing from the form post in the list, you *may* still need a form...it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Posting your edit view might help us get you a better answer.

Comment: Ok, I added an update to my answer to show how I would reference the value in the view, but now that I see what you're doing, here's what I would suggest...a separate view that does each action: create, update and delete. There are also generic views that will do these actions for you: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/ Also, read up on forms for models: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/ as you really need to be getting the values from the cleaned data collection of a form, not from request.POST.

Comment: Thank, Brandon. I'll read those links. One thing I'm still not quite clear on is how to reference the form fields. So far I have  `Email.objects.filter(email=email).delete()` What would 'email' be here? (I need to read up on my forms, too...)

Comment: Forms are classes that can inherit their fields from Models (forms.ModelForm) or they can be non-model form (forms.Form). In the filter statement, the 'email' variable would need to come from the request.POST collection, which isn't a very safe way to access that value.

Comment: OK -- I have gotten the delete to work with the following: `Email.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).delete()`.

Comment: In your original code, the name attribute of the email field is set to {{ email.id }}, which means you would have to know the ID beforehand to get it out of the request.POST dictionary. I have to sign off for the evening, but I can send you a working example project tomorrow.

Comment: ok -- thank you for your help. The last thing left for me is to figure out how to reference the id/(original) email for the update button

Comment: Ok, I made a sample app for you: http://btaylordesign.com/static/transfer/example.tar.gz. The url patterns begin at /people/ Let me know if you have any questions. I didn't use generics so you can better see what's going on. Hope that helps you out.